# Regexp matching for assignment operations in C

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to write a regexp that catches assignments equal signs within conditional statements in C language that I already extracted (using python module `re`).

My attempt:

```
exp = re.compile(r'\(\s*[0-9A-Za-z_]+\s*[^!<>=]=[^=]')
```

While working for a number of cases, it fails to match a simple case like the following string:

```
'(c=getc(pp)) == EOF'
```

Can someone please explain why my regexp is not a match for this string, and how could I make it better ? I'm aware that some weird cases might still elude me, but I can treat those manually, the purpose is to do the bulk of the legwork automatically.

Comment: the range to match "less than, different" ... prevents the match because it contains =

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre How can I avoid matching for `==` or `!=` then ?

Comment: why not just `exp = re.compile(r'\(\s*[0-9A-Za-z_]+\s*=[^=]')` then, that would match a single equal sign, nothing else.

Comment: It does seem to work, I'm testing it a bit, if you answer the question I will probably accept your answer ! Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[^!<>=]` following your identifier prevents `=` to be matched after `c`.

If your intention is to match assignments, try to match only one equal sign after the identifier, like this:

```
exp = re.compile(r'\(\s*[0-9A-Za-z_]+\s*=[^=]')

print(exp.search('(c=getc(pp)) == EOF'))
```

which results in:

```
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 4), match='(c=g'>
```

Comment: I do match for more cases like the example I gave with your regexp, but there is something I don't quite get. This regexp is not anchored, yet it does not match any string that starts with something else, say another parenthesis or a blank. For example `' (c=getc(pp)) == EOF'`is not a match. How come ?

Comment: because you're using `match`, I'm using `search`

Comment: Oh, ok, my bad for not knowing the `re` module enough ! Thank you again, I am accepting your answer, glad to have found help from a fellow Toulousain ;)

Comment: I just hope I didn't help a competitor :) (note: I don't care)

Comment: Since I work for a subcontractor at CNES we should be fine :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this does not work is `[^!<>=]=`, which makes your code look for a character which is not `=` followed by a character which is `=`. I can see your intention in doing so, but it's the wrong way.

For the simple, case have a look at the following expression:

```
[0-9A-Za-z_]+\s*=\s*[0-9A-Za-z_]+(\(\s*[0-9A-Za-z_]*\s*\))?
```

This matches the `c=getc(pp)` part of your source, because it looks for a `=` which is either followed (or preceded) by optional whitespaces and characters or numbers. Already this prevents the regex from matching `==`, `<=`, `!=`, or `>=`.

Aside of that it also looks if the right hand side is a function or simply a variable or just a number (optional match through `?` for the bracket-part at the end of the expression). Note also the `*` for the matching part within the braces (`[0-9A-Za-z_]*`), which enables you to match function calls without parameters.

Works for:

```
(c=getc(p)) == EOF
(c =getc()) == EOF
(c=getc( )) == EOF
(c = getc( p )) == EOF
(c = i) == EOF
(c=10) == EOF
```

This will not work for constructs, such as `x = y(z())` (and surely many more).

Aside of this being said, I recommend the following link (not exactly your question, but really nice insights):
[Regular expression to recognize variable declarations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993187/regular-expression-to-recognize-variable-declarations-in-c)

Comment: Thank you for your complementary insight !

Comment: You're welcome. In the case that you put more effort into your expression, let us know your solution.

Comment: Besides adding `&\->*` to the set corresponding to the variable name to take into account structures, pointers and adresses, I'm affraid my regexp knowledge is very basic so I don't see what else could be done !