# Regular expression: alphanumerics without pure numerics

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the names of variables from a function string.

A variable can be [a-zA-Z0-9]+ but **not** a real number notated like 1, 3.5, 1e4, 1e5...

Is there a smart way of doing this?

Here's a M(not)WE in python:

```
import re
pattern = r"[a-zA-z0-9.]+"
function_string = "(A+B1)**2.5"
re.findall(pattern, function_string)
```

The above code returns:

```
A, B1 and 2.5.
```

My desired output is

```
A and B1.
```

And here's a nice way of testing the regular expressions:
https://regex101.com/r/fv0DfR/1

Comment: So what is the question? The desired output should be?

Comment: The [regex pattern for C variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993187/regular-expression-to-recognize-variable-declarations-in-c) might be of use.

Comment: Does a variable have to start with a non numeric character? ie is 12a valid?

Comment: @JGNI good point, I will think about that. Variables can't start with a non-numeric in my application (python) but at the same time the entire function string is probably erroneous if any of the contained expressions starts with a non-numeric.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this Regex:

```
\b(?!\d)[a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

**[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fv0DfR/5)**

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - matches a word boundary
- `(?!\d)` - negative lookahead to make sure that the next character is not a digit. This will make sure that the variable name does not start with a digit. Will also exclude words like `1e3`
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` - matches 1+ letters or digits

If you want those variables also which start with a digit and are alphanumeric, you can use [`\b(?!\d+(?:[eE]\d+)?\b)[a-zA-Z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/fyzAim/1)

Comment: `1E4` and it fails, if it counts. Although its okay since the OP did not mention anything else, cheers

Comment: @user5173426 Updated

Comment: mmh I was a bit fast at accepting your answer but I see you're adjusting still, thank you. It would be good indeed to have both `1e4` and `1E4` excluded, but I don't care about hexadecimals, nor complex numbers etc. Will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
pattern = r'[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z0-9_]{0,31}'
function_string = "(A+B1)2.5"

print(re.findall(pattern, function_string))
```

OUTPUT:

```
['A', 'B1']
```

Comment: Your link shows my regex. Also, the regex fails for strings like `1e4`