# gcc: warn about every variable definition without initialisiation

Tags: c, gcc

Is there a warning flag so that gcc will warn about every variable that is defined and not immediately initialized? I know about `-Wuninitialized` but it does not warn about every case.
Consider this code:

```
int foo(int i)
{
  int a;
  a= i%2 ? 0x42 : 42;
  return a;
}
```

Even tho this is perfectly valid code and does not cause UB, i would like a warning for this. The line `int a;` should be replaced by `int a=0;`. Can i tell gcc to warn about `int a;`?

Edit, a more complex example:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int foo(void)
{
  int a;
  if(1==scanf("%i",&a))
  {
    return a;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Here i want gcc to warn about `int a;`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCC -Wuninitialized / -Wmaybe-uninitialized issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14132898/gcc-wuninitialized-wmaybe-uninitialized-issues)

Comment: @EricPostpischil I tried it with `-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wunused -Wuninitialized`, gcc does still not warn.

Comment: @KrishnaKanthYenumula No. The linked question talks about initializing a variable in a `if` body or somewhere else where the PC may or may not land. I talk about initializing it in the same statement as the definition.

Comment: @EricPostpischil No. There is also the `-Wswitch-default` which is not enabled by any of`-Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Wunused -Wuninitialized`.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem a language problem, so I don't think GCC will ever react; actually, it is *defining* a value for `a` that might be warned against by some linter:

```
 int a = 0;
         ^-- warning: redundant initialisation (value is immediately discarded)
 a= i%2 ? 0x42 : 42;
```

What you can, perhaps, do - but this will not catch *all* possible cases - is recognize the issue at the static level.

I myself do this for some specific cases (which is why I have trained myself to write code in what is sometimes a unusual way -- for example, `free(p); p = NULL;` on a single line, or if p is to be immediately discarded, then `free(p); // p = NULL;`, so no pointer can ever point to freed memory, and I track this using `grep`. The same with `fclose(fp); fp = NULL`).

In this case, at least for the common data types and simple initializations, you can recognize the unassignment with a regex too:

```
((unsigned\\s+)?(long\\s+)?(int|char|float|double)...
```

(Not a real regex, just throwing in tokens at random. You may want to look at [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12993187/regular-expression-to-recognize-variable-declarations-in-c) to this effect).

Once you have a means of singling out all definitions, any definition that does not include an equal sign is suspect and can be printed for further analysis. You can avoid a "unneeded initialization" by writing `int a; //OK` and ignore the lines containing '//OK'.

Comment: I have to admit, the example i have is not very good since i could replace it with `int a=i%2?0x42:42;`

Comment: There is a problem with the regex solution, it matches `struct` definitions as well. the line `int a;` is also inside `struct foobar { int a; int b; };`, where no initialization is needed nor possible.

Answer (score 0):

In your code sample, being warned to replace the `int a;` line with `int a = 0;` will be counter-productive. A good compiler would/should warn you about the *latter*, as there you are assigning a value to `a` that will never be used (the value is immediately overwritten in the following line of code).

Comment: I see that other people may like other patterns more than the patterns i like. But i want to initialize every variable in the same statement as i define them. I updated the question and added a more complex example.

Comment: @Cheatah I agree. It is only when an uninitialized variable is actually *used* that a compiler (or even a linter) should warn.